# How do I install 'containers' features on Windows server 2019 Build 1809?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I recently installed Windows Server 2019, but I noticed it doesn't have an option for installing `Containers`.    I assumed any Windows Server OS would have the ability to add a `Containers` channel, however I don't see anything online to do this.

This version is actually "Microsoft Hyper-V Server", however, its not clear that Hyper-V server is fundamentally different from regular Windows Server OS installations.

- Is there a way to enable the 'Containers' feature on Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019 (1809) ?
- Is there a way to upgrade Micrsoft's Hyper-V Server to a Containers compatible 1909 server ?
- What is the fundamental difference between Microsoft's Hyper-V Server and a regular Microsoft 2019 Windows Server OS?

Note: I installed this onto a laptop over a USB stick, and did a lot of work to upgrade drivers and so on to support laptop features like Wi-Fi, hence my reluctance to completely reinstall the operating system .

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's some pretty nasty hackery right there. Just how many different Windows Server editions did you have to rip things out of to get to this state?

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between a Windows Server and a Windows Hyper-V Server is that the latter only contains enough infrastructure to be a host to a number of Hyper-V virtual machines.

I'm afraid the upgrade path is to replace it with a full version of Windows Server 2019.

Comment: is that something that can be done to a Hyper-V Windows Server OS ? Or are you usggesting, there is no upgrade path

Comment: I'm stating that there is no upgrade path. Hyper-V Server is designed to only host Hyper-V instances. If you want to do anything else with it, you're hooped. The only way to enable the Containers feature is to replace the entire OS with a full Windows Server install, or install a full Windows Server in a Hyper-V instance.

Comment: Yes, and that's why Hyper-V Server is free...